# Is there a "map until" or "map while" construct in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I use the following code:

```
 for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if item2.add_item_if_belongs(item1):
            break
```

If I did not have the `break` statement I would replace the above with:

```
for item1 in list1:
    map(lambda item2: item2.add_item_if_belongs(item1), list2)
```

Is there some way to "map until", or "map while"?

Comment: what is `add_item_if_belongs`?

Comment: It returns True and "consumes" the item it receives if it meets certain criteria, otherwise it returns False.

Comment: I don't think there is one, what's wrong with the first code?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I am asking a question because I don't know the definite answer.

Comment: Using `map` (or list comprehensions) for side effects is evil.

Comment: Less lines of codes does not always increase readability of performance. The first version is fine.

Comment: Long story short: if you're dealing with iterables, look at [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). Also, do listen to what you're being told - the advice is free!

Comment: If anything personally I'd have more lines of code, `if item2.belongs(item1):` followed by `item2.add_item(item1)`, then `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the output of map apparently, so what you need is more of an "apply" kind of function. You could move the innermost loop to its own function.

```
def apply_until( fun, vals ):
    for val in vals:
        if fun(val):
            break
```

But you shouldn't drop clarity for shorter code though, IMO, the for loops are as clear as it gets and fast too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, islice

for item1 in list1:
    map(lambda item2: item2.add_item(item1), 
        islice(dropwhile(lambda item2: item2.does_not_belong(item1),
               list2), 1))
```

So drop all the items that don't belong then take only the first that does. Of course this makes the `map` pointless as it only ever operates on a single item and you ignore the single item list it created.

Needless to say the original `for` loops are clearer.